# How can I achieve this view?

Tags: android, android-view

[image]

I've tried using an HorizontalScrollView with a linearLayout inside. It looked exactly like the picture, but I don't want to use that ScrollView because on the launch, the scrolling bar is shown, and this is not what I want.

I've also tried a relativeLayout with every view aligned with each other, but the last view is scaled down, to fit the small space left.

Any tip?

Comment: ScrollView is the best option ? yes maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, You can enable or disable scrolling bar using this `setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled()`

```
Scrool.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Gallery is being deprecated. So, the recommended way to achieve this would be HorizontalScrollView. You can turn on/off the scrollbars if you want them not to be shown during launch, and then, after launch turn them on.

> This class was deprecated in API level 16. This widget is no longer
>   supported. Other horizontally scrolling widgets include
>   HorizontalScrollView and ViewPager from the support library.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give a try to andoid `Gallery` View. That I guess would suffice your need as far as I can visualize it.

Answer (score 0):

Found out a solution:

Created a RelativeLayout with a Horizontal LinearLayout inside. The RelativeLayout (the highest parent) with a width of 1500dp. Then nothing is scalled.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="1500dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#ffffffff">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/techinc_splash_1" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/techinc_splash_1" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/techinc_splash_1" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```